# How to access Active directory from a website?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am having a small issue that i need to know more about, I have built a website that authenticates users through the Active directory, It was done using `ldap` functions in PHP and it is working perfectly.The issue is that i don't know how to access the Active directory after i upload the website to the hosting server. what are the steps am i supposed to do?

here is the code for further understanding :-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $adServer = "ldap://Qarunho.local";

    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $ldaprdn = 'Qarunho' . "\\" . $username;

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

    if(!empty($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['password'])){
        if ($bind) {
            $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
            $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=Qarunho,dc=Local",$filter);
            ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
            for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
            {
                if($info['count'] > 1)
                    break;
                            $_SESSION['sn'] = $info[$i]["givenname"][0].'     '.$info[$i]["sn"][0];
                            header('location:manager_page.php'); 
            }
            @ldap_close($ldap);
        } 
?>
```

thanks in advance ..... :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where this is hosted.  If the webserver is local to your current ActiveDirectory domain, then the issue could be that your webserver doesn't have a clear security/network path to one of your domain controllers.

If the web server is *not* local to your current AD domain (e.g. you're putting this on a remote host like godaddy or hostgator), then you'll need to use a different authentication method.  Specifically, you'll want to take a look at:

[SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) and google around for how it interacts with ADFS (Active Directory Federated Services).  The challenge is that you have to create a way that your private network with it's privately hosted domain controllers can send/receive extremely sensitive, extremely-needs-to-be-secure data to the web.

Answer (score 0):

That's issue, because your LDAP is on the local computer, right ?

but, your website is on the server and have public IP. So, you must have tunnel to your local LDAP or you can publish your LDAP to the outside, so your website can access your LDAP.

Comment: yes this is the exact issue, i am asking how i can do that brother? how to publish my ldap to outside as you said?

Comment: try using Dynamic DNS to point your domain-name or your IP Address from your public IP.

this's like you make tunnel to your local IP.
Or,
you can use OpenLDAP hosting in a Cloud Virtual Server.